# При запуске build.gradle ошибка

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, gradle

Я пишу на koltin в IntelliJ IDEA, при запуске build.gradle появляеться следущяя ошибка:

```
Unsupported Java. 
Your build is currently configured to use Java 20.0.2 and Gradle 8.2.

Possible solution:
 - Use Java 19 as Gradle JVM: Open Gradle settings 
 - Upgrade Gradle wrapper to 4.5 version and re-import the project
```

код build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.3.2'
}
```

В настройках Gradle пытался изменить версию JVM на более старую(17-19), не помогло.

Comment: Думаю переход на Gradle 8.3 решит проблему: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html